# Does Selenium send_keys need sanitizing?

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium to automate some manual process. My Python code looks like this

```
user_detail_form.find_element_by_css_selector("input#address").send_keys(user.address)
```

`user.address` is from user input. Do I need to clean it before passing to `send_keys`? E.g. will it be possible for an attacker to trigger chrome console or execute arbitrary code by exploiting unsanitized `user.address`?

Comment: `sanitation` in the form of?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to clean it before passing to send_keys?

I would not say, that it should be definitly done. But it is a good practice to make sure that `input` field is clean before the script executes `.send_keys()` method. There are situations, where the input field can contain already 'old' information and the script will fail, if you don't clear the field before `sendKeys()`.

> Will it be possible for an attacker to trigger chrome console or
>   execute arbitrary code by exploiting unsanitized `user.address`?

I don't know if it is possible, but anyway it's better to clean up what is possible to 'clean'.